# Spring Boot, Spring Data, Hibernate WebSphere 8.5.5.9 NullPointer for JPARepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, websphere, spring-data-jpa

I've had quite a few problems deploying a Spring Boot app into Websphere 8.5.5.9, but this one has me a bit stumped.

I am getting a NullPointer for my Autowired JPARepository Bean when invoked via my CXF Rest endpoint, however data gets inserted fine via the SpringBoot CommandLineRunner() method.

Code for the project can be found at [github](https://github.com/ally-jarrett/sb-cxf-jpa-was).

I configure the project's class loader as PARENT_LAST to get CXF working correctly and I set a ContextRoot of '/cxf'

I can see the app loads up correctly, finding the DB & creating the tables etc..

To hit the endpoint i goto: host:port/cxf/services/sayHello/all

I am grabbing a H2 JNDI datasource from WebSphere like so:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.was.spring.cxf.dto")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
      entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
      basePackages = { "com.was.spring.cxf.repository" })
@Order(1)
public class DSConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DSConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSourceFactoryBean() {

        final JndiObjectFactoryBean jofb = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jofb.setJndiName("jdbc/ccbIntDataSource");

        return jofb;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        final Boolean initDB = false;
        final DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) dataSourceFactoryBean().getObject();
        //final Boolean initDB = environment.getProperty("init.db", Boolean.class, Boolean.FALSE);
        logger.debug("Is initializing DB from sql scripts enabled? init.db={}", initDB);

        if (initDB) {
            logger.debug("Start initializing DB with scripts:");
            final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
            //populator.addScripts(dbInitScripts);
            populator.setSqlScriptEncoding("UTF-8");
            DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, dataSource);
            logger.debug("End initializing DB");
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

And I setup my EMF like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.was.spring.cxf")
@Order(2)
public class JPAConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JPAConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        try {
            logger.info("Using DataSource URL: " + dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.was.spring.cxf.model", "com.was.spring.cxf.dto"});

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return em;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", H2Dialect.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I have a really simple interface & implementation:

```
// Interface
    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response getAllCustomers();

// Impl

    @Override
    public Response getAllCustomers() {
        logger.info("INVOKING.....");

        if (repository == null){
            logger.info("REPO IS NULL....");
        }

        Iterable<Customer> customers = repository.findAll();
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            logger.info(customer.toString());
        }

        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(customers).build();
    }
```

And finally I have the Repository itself:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

However when I try to use the JPARepository I get the following exception:

```
[3/14/17 19:13:46:395 UTC] 00000063 SystemOut     O 2017-03-14 19:13:46.395  INFO 122 --- [ebContainer : 0] c.was.spring.cxf.impl.HelloServiceImpl   : INVOKING.....
[3/14/17 19:13:46:395 UTC] 00000063 SystemOut     O 2017-03-14 19:13:46.395  INFO 122 --- [ebContainer : 0] c.was.spring.cxf.impl.HelloServiceImpl   : REPO IS NULL....
[3/14/17 19:13:46:403 UTC] 00000063 SystemOut     O 2017-03-14 19:13:46.402  WARN 122 --- [ebContainer : 0] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Application {http://impl.cxf.spring.was.com/}HelloServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3928) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) [na:CCX.CF [o1537.01]]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) [na:CCX.CF [o1537.01]]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.was.spring.cxf.impl.HelloServiceImpl.getAllCustomers(HelloServiceImpl.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:2.6 (07-13-2016)]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

Comment: afaik spring boot doesn't have out-of-the-box support for apache cxf like it has for jersey. So you will need to setup cxf spring integration yourself

Comment: I dont believe its a CXF fault, I setup the JAXRSServerFactoryBean in an additional cofig class and it works fine,  if you look at the Caused By trace: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.was.spring.cxf.impl.HelloServiceImpl.getAllCustomers(HelloServiceImpl.java:37) ~[classes/:na] its the JPARepository returning null.

Comment: And that it is `null` will only happen if it gets an instance outside of the scope of spring. Which will only happen in the CXF spring integration isn't setup correctly. Spring should manage the instance creation not spring and in your case cxf is. Also web sphere ships with CXF (if I recall correctly) so it could even be a class loading issue...